# XElement ReplaceWith

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I would like to replace a specific node with string.

It successfully replace the node but instead of `"<div>"`, it appear `"&lt;div&gt;"`

What should I do to make it into `"<div>"`?

I have tried XElement.Parse but it will give me error as I replace node with `"</div><div>"`

```
foreach (var node in Nodes)
{
   var newElement = XElement.Parse("</div><div>");
   node.ReplaceWith(sbb.ToString);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using?

Comment: Indeed, a [mcve] would really help here. It sounds like you're not really trying to replace a node with a string, but with another element - so you should build the `XElement` to replace it with. If you pass in a string, LINQ to XML will expect that you mean that to be the *text* content, which is why it's escaping the angle brackets.

Comment: You do not have XML.  You have html.  Xml Linq (XDocument/XElement) will not all the time with html.  If you have xml embedded in html then use :  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string xml)

Comment: It will give me "Unexpected end tag error". Do XElement.Parse allow start with end tag? Something like this XElement.Parse("</div><div>");

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
XElement foo = XElement.Parse("<div>example</div>");

foo.ReplaceNodes(XElement.Parse("<div>" + otherMarkUp + "</div>").Nodes());
```

Based on your code, you should replace with the newElement.

```
foreach (var node in Nodes)
{
   var newElement = XElement.Parse("<div></div>");
   node.ReplaceWith(newElement);
}
```

If the above does not work, please share some more code to work on it.

Comment: It will give me error 'Unexpected end tag. Line 1, position 3.'

Comment: Based on your updated answer, I did some changes. If you run the modified code, what happens? Is the Parse line that gives you the error?

Comment: Do XElement.Parse allow to start with end tag?

Comment: Oh my God, I just saw this. Of course not. Parsing validates the XML and creates a node